# simple error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: sql

I am trying to List the full name and the total number of transactions handled by the full time
employee and Rank the results in descending order on the total number of transactions.

This is what I have

```
select 
    concat( e.efirst, e.elast ) ename, 
    count(*) total_transactions
from 
    transactions t 
    join employees e on t.employeeid = e.employeeid
where 
    e.etype = 'Fulltime' 
group by
    t.employeeid 
order by
    total_transactions desc;
```

Comment: well, you need to group by the expression you are using for the employee name, not the employeeid

Comment: I need to group by ename?

Comment: you need to group by the same expression you are using for `ename`, you can't use that alias directly in the `GROUP BY`. So, you have to use `GROUP BY concat( e.efirst, e.elast )`, which will be kind of weird, since there are no spaces between the first and last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `concat(e.efirst, e.elast)` to group by:

```
select 
    concat(e.efirst, e.elast) ename, 
    count(*) total_transactions
from 
    transactions t 
    join employees e on t.employeeid = e.employeeid
where 
    e.etype = 'Fulltime' 
group by
    t.employeeid, concat(e.efirst, e.elast) 
order by
    total_transactions desc;
```

Answer (score 4):

When computing aggregates when grouped by a foreign key you'll want to `JOIN` the principal relation (in this case `employee`) in an outer-query, as it's a separate concern from the aggregate.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( CONCAT( employee.efirst, ' ' ), employee.elast ) AS employee_name, 
    employee_id,
    total_transactions
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            employeeid AS employee_id,
            COUNT(*) AS total_transactions
        FROM
            transactions
        GROUP BY
            employeeid
    ) AS sq
    INNER JOIN employee ON sq.employee_id = employee.employeeid
WHERE
    employee.etype = 'Fulltime'
ORDER BY
    total_transactions desc;
```

Comment: I get error "ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments"

Comment: @MikeGoedken I've corrected my answer. I forgot that Oracle's `CONCAT` isn't variadic.

Comment: This is the right answer, since not only fixes the error when grouping, it also gives the right results in case 2 or more employees have the same name

Comment: it's the `e.` alias, needs to be `employee.efirst` and `employee.elast`

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` expressions should match the unaggregated expressions in the `select`, so:

```
select ( e.efirst || ' ' || e.elast ) as ename, 
       count(*) total_transactions
from transactions t join
     employees e
     on t.employeeid = e.employeeid
where e.etype = 'Fulltime' 
group by ( e.efirst || ' ' || e.elast ) 
order by total_transactions desc;
```

I added a space between the names as well and switched to using the concatenation operator.

This assumes that employee names are distinct.  If this is not the case, then you should be including the employee id in the `select`, s you can distinguish amongst those with the same name.

Comment: This won't work if multiple employees share the same name.